# Spring Data JPA - is sort by field in attribute possible?

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables in the DB modelling a one-to-one relationship.

The entity class contains something similar to the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_table")
public class MyEntity {
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private MyOtherEntity myOtherEntity
}
```

Then we have the other class modelling the table with one-to-one relationship:

```
Entity
@Table(name = "my_other_table")
public class MyOtherEntity {
    private String name;
}
```

And a simplified repository:

```
public class MyRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT m from MyEntity m INNER JOIN  m.myOtherEntity mo")
    Page<MyEntity> search(Pageable pageable);
}
```

This repository is invoked by means of a controller that receives a `Pageable` as parameter

How should the query param look when sorting by the `name` field in `MyOtherEntity`?

I've tried:

```
sort=myOtherEntity.name
```

But I get

```
ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list
```

I also don't have the option of printing the generated SQL.

Comment: I've gotten it working like this with native queries and projection, but I've honestly never tried like this when returning the full entity. have you tried adding mo.name to the SELECT clause? (Also in some places you're using MyOtherEntity and in others MyOtherObject)

Comment: I'll try with mo.name, but, intuitively, that would bring in more data than the object that the result set would map to (a MyEntity), so that might cause further issues. Sorry for the myOtherObject, it was an error when simplifying the example, the actual code uses correct naming.

Comment: assuming the exception is coming from your JPA implementation you should add that as a tag at least.

Comment: I've already added spring-data-jpa, but another tag surely won't hurt. Thank you for the advice, Jens!

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions) you can disregard JPQL entirely and do something like this :

```
Page<MyEntity> findAllOrderByMyOtherEntityName();
```

You should always prefer spring data queries over JPQL **if** your methods will be readable enough ... its easier and less error-prone. Plus : it decouples strings and program logic, which is what every serious developer should do.

And if you want to create more complex statements : have a look at QueryDSL - it enables you to write typesafe queries whilst having them nicely integrated into spring data JPA, they are officially supported (!)